# Exporting variables in shell

Tags: shell

I have a question. What is the difference between exporting variables with `export`command and with `.` (dot) command? Please, explain it clearly

Comment: What do you mean by exporting with `.`? That sources a file, i.e. executes its contents in the current shell just as if you had typed it out yourself.

Comment: export does this: http://ss64.com/bash/export.html
dot does this: http://ss64.com/bash/source.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat of an apples and oranges question. They are not identical functions.

The export command is used to set variables, so you've got two choices:

```
variable=value
export variable=value
```

If you want to run another shell script, you have several choices:

```
shellScriptName.sh  (no prefix or qualifiers)
/bin/sh shellScriptName
. shellScriptName.sh
```

Variable assignment does just that, sets a variable. The export controls the scope of visibility of the variable you've just set (in particular, does it get exported to child processes).

As for shell scripts, the first two are essentially identical and run a shell script in another process. In that case, any variables set/exported will not be visible in the calling shell. When you use . it sources the shell script as if it were inline in the current shell script /process (like an import) so variable assignments from the child shell are visible in the current shell.

Comment: `export` also makes it visible up to the login shell. So if I spawn a shell that spawns another shell that does `export VAR=3`, then `echo $VAR` after those shells have terminated will show `3`.